# Redmine plugins scripting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm new to javascript, Redmine and RoR. So far I have read and understood the plugin development [tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial). But when I try to do things on my own they won't work...

If I use this:

```
<% content_for :header_tags do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'script', :plugin => 'my_plugin' %>
<% end %>
```

it will generate the correct link code on page source but there will be no scripts loaded to `redmine_root/public/plugin_assets`. Is that supposed to happen?

I would like to make this [hello world example](http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial#hello-world) work.

But as far as I can understand, it will never work on the whole Redmine app if the scripts don't get loaded to `redmine_root/public/plugin_assets`.

If someone can help me out with understand why the scripts are not loading and how to properly use scripts under Redmine I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is code sample copy-paste from your project code? Or You typed it manually with misprints? `%` and `=` signs are missed in some places, must be `<%= ... %>` or `<% ... %>`
2. What the content of `redmine_root/public/plugin_assets` folder?
   It must have plugin folder named same as your plugin, then `images`, `javascripts` and `stylesheets` folders, like here:

   ```
   redmine_root
     ...
     plugins
       your_plugin # your plugin name
       other_plugins
     ...
     public
       ...
       plugin_assets
         your_plugin # your plugin name, must match with your plugin name in redmine_root/plugins
           javascripts
             your_script.js
           images
           stylesheets
          other_plugins
   ```

In this case `javascript_include_tag` will works correctly with standart parameters (script and plugin names).

Comment: Yes. I mistyped it. I will correct it.
redmine_root/public/plugin_assets = empty.

Comment: Place your javascript file to plugin_assets as in my answer and try again

Comment: I will try it out... but tutorial says:

"When starting the application, plugin assets are automatically copied to public/plugin_assets/polls/ to make them available through your web server. So any change to your plugin stylesheets or javascripts needs an application restart."

So, doing it manually beats the purpose a little.

Comment: It works. Is there a way to automatically load stuff?

Comment: Huh, I not wondered by this question. I just placed neccessary stuff to plugin assets folder.